# How to toggle the visibility of buttons with a timer?

Tags: ios, nstimer

Ive added an NSTimer to make my rate button appear by setting the action to Hidden NO

```
NSMethodSignature *sgn = [self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(onTick:)];
    NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature: sgn];
    [inv setTarget: self];
    [inv setSelector:@selector(onTick:)];

    NSTimer *t = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval: 10.0
                                     invocation:inv
                                        repeats:YES];

    NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runner addTimer: t forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Then

```
-(void)onTick:(NSTimer *)timer {
_Rateapp1.hidden = NO;
_ratebomb.hidden = NO;
_ratelab1.hidden = NO;
}
```

BUT how do I make the button re-Appear with YES?

Comment: You setup a repeating timer. What do you want to happen every 10 seconds? Are you trying to toggle the buttons on and off every 10 seconds?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to toggle it every 10 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your goal is to toggle the display of the buttons each time the timer goes off, you simply do:

```
- (void)onTick:(NSTimer *)timer {
    _Rateapp1.hidden = !_Rateapp1.hidden;
    _ratebomb.hidden = !_ratebomb.hidden;
    _ratelab1.hidden = !_ratelab1.hidden;
}
```

And you can replace all of your timer creation code with:

```
NSTimer *t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(onTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

No need for the invocation or runloop code. I also suggest you keep a reference to the timer so you can invalidate (stop) the timer when needed.

Comment: Curious - what tweaks were needed? Were your requirements different than assumed? If so, clarifying the question would help.

Comment: Well when I used NSTimer *t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(onTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; <--- that I got a caution error.. Then when i added ---> NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runner addTimer: t forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode]; <--- It went away!

Comment: What was the error? Was it about an unused variable? Do not use the runloop code with the call to `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`. Remove the unused variable if that is the problem. But as I stated in the answer, you really should be keeping a reference to the timer.

Comment: how do I keep a reference and how will i activate it to stop?